# Backup software with a boot manager

Tags: backup

I'm looking for backup software that functions as follows:

- Acts as a boot manager and loads before the OS. Boots into default OS
  after n seconds.
- Can restore the OS volume from a cloned image that's stored on a
  partition on the hard drive just by selecting that option from the
  boot manager.
- Works even on ancient hardware (1990s era).

I've been told this software exists, but the person can't remember the name of it. The basic idea is to use this for terminal computers that can be restored to a clean installation with minimal effort if the OS gets bricked by the user or a power outage.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: You'd need to do a lot of customization, but start wtih CloneZilla - meant to be run from bootable media and create or restore disk images.